# How to Save Data in PDF file from SQL in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

My Question is that i am working on a project in which a email has been send to the customer this mail contain a pdf file in which the report of the customer has been display.
Please any one suggest me the answer that it is possible or not if YES then you may give me the answer of that question.
if NO then Please Suggest  me any other solution to what i do?

Comment: @Akshat this is my question

Comment: FPDF, TCPDF, SwiftMailer, et cetera et cetera.

Comment: use something like dompdf or Zends pdf library to create the pdf file and then attach it to the email

Answer (score 0):

Run through the [tutorials](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/index.php) at [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org) you can use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org) or many of the other packages mentioned in the comments to make your form. You can then use your database to create these PDFs for whatever use you need and attach them to emails to send to your clients.